# How set correct nginx.conf to run as a proxy with alpine docker image?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and the following `nginx.conf` file I copied from [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-java-scorekeep/blob/master/.ebextensions/nginx/nginx.conf):

```
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    33282;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default     "upgrade";
  }

#   upstream api {
#       server 127.0.0.1:8001;
#   }

  server {
      listen        80 default_server;
    #   root /var/app/current/public;

      location / {
      }

      location /api {
          proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8001;
          proxy_http_version  1.1;

          proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

      client_header_timeout 60;
      client_body_timeout   60;
      keepalive_timeout     60;
      gzip                  off;
      gzip_comp_level       4;
  }
}
```

I have an http server running on port `8001` locally and I run the docker container locally as well. As far as I understand, requests to `http://localhost/api` should be forwarded to the server, however when I make a request to `http://127.0.0.1/api/health` which a supported server route, I get the error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

When I make a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/health` I get a `200` response as expected. Not sure what's wrong with my nginx configuration?

---

**EDIT:** the initial error was because I was not exposing the port when running the nginx container; however after exposing the port as follows:

`docker run --rm -it -p 3001:80 nginx_container_id`

I get the following nginx error:

```
[error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/health", host: "127.0.0.1:3001"
```

**EDIT2:** While the answer suggests a solution for Linux OS for macOS the solution would be to use `proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:8001;` as per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/)

Comment: how do you run the container? can you add this line? (or compose?) are you using host network if you're server run locally?

Comment: what about `docker run --rm -p 80:80 --network="host" nginx_container_id` ?

Comment: @ItayB this would've worked if I were on Linux but I'm on mac, so I need to use `proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:8001;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NGINX configuration, `proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8001;` means that NGINX tries to access 8001 port in its container. `127.0.0.1` does not represent your host's IP address. I prefer the network bridge mode and use the network bridge gateway address.

```sh
docker run --rm -it --network="bridge" -p 3001:80 nginx_container_id
```

I get the network bridge's gateway address with `docker network inspect bridge`.

Changed the Nginx configuration (Assume that the bridge gateway address `172.17.0.1`). Preferring gateway address is a little trick that you don't know container's IP address, only need port value.

```
proxy_pass          http://172.17.0.1:8001;
```

instead of

```
proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8001;
```

If you are using a firewall, you must allow access between docker containers.

For iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.17.0.1/16 -j ACCEPT
```

For firewall-cmd

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=172.17.0.1/16 accept' --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: You correctly identified the issue. But your answer doesn't work on mac (which is the computer I'm using). Just add that mac users need to use `proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:8001;` in nginx config (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/_ and I will accept your answer.

Comment: I use this setup on my linux environments. I don't experience on Macs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be getting your wires crossed a bit.

The container only exposes port `80`, but you're proxy passing over to port `8001`.

And to further muddy the waters you're opening port `3001` to the container's port `80` in your `run` command.

Try proxy passing to `80` instead of `8001`, and keep your `run` command at `3001:80`. Then try connecting with `3001` included in the URL.